# What should I grow in my rocky+sandy+salty soil?

Tags: shrubs, planting, outdoor, pines

I'm trying to improve this area next to my home with some plantings. What I'd like to accomplish:

1. Make the area look nicer
2. Discourage people from walking their dogs on the property
3. Discourage people from leaving trash on the property

We're at the New Jersey shore next to a saltwater bay, and the soil is rocky, sandy, and salty. The white pines and junipers grow well enough, but the pines dump huge amounts of needles on the ground. They provide a modest amount of shade. I'm open to planting anything here as long as it is suitable and will grow -- shrubs, bushes, flowers, etc. What advice would you give me? Thanks!

[image: A view of the area]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at beach-rose (*Rosa rugosa*). I don't know if the light will be ok, but they are very hardy and definitely salt-tolerant. They're also (at least in my opinion) good-looking plants, with thorns (that will discourage the dogs/walkers), and you can make a very nice tea from the rose hips they produce.